# Add two paths together using UIBezierPath in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, intersection, uibezierpath

I have 2 lines drawn using `UIBezierPath`, how can i combine point to form a shape inform of letter `X`. I want to join both lines together

Path 1

```
let path1 = UIBezierPath()
path1.move(to: .zero)
path1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
path1.close()
path1.lineWidth = 1.0
UIColor.blue.set()
path1.stroke()
path1.fill()
```

Path 2

```
let path2 = UIBezierPath()
path2.move(to: .zero)
path2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50))
path2.close()
path2.lineWidth = 1.0
UIColor.red.set()
path2.stroke()
path2.fill()
```

Comment: ```path1.append(path2)```

Comment: Doesn't work, tried that already

Comment: What result do you expect? UIBezierPath is a vector representation of drawing.

Comment: I'm new to custom drawing in iOS so i don't know

Comment: I mean you need to explain what do you want to draw first. And I'll try to help you then.

Comment: I'm trying to draw a shape inform of letter `X` if that makes sense. I thought i could just create 2 paths and add them together but that doesnt work

Comment: You don't really need to use 2 paths here then. Until these lines have the same width and color. :)

Comment: Ok how do i do that?

Comment: Just combine the functions you already have. `move()` moves "pencil" without drawing any lines and `addLine()` draws a line. So your path building code should look similar to "move, addLine, move addLine". That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use proper `CGPoint` values

If your view bounds value is `(0,0,100,100)`

- Move to (0,0)
- Addline to (100,100)
- Mode to (0,100)
- Addline to (100,0)

Try this

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: .zero)
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY))
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.minY))
path.close()
path.lineWidth = 1.0
UIColor.blue.set()
path.stroke()
path.fill()
```